# I changed a resource in Eclipse and the app displays the old resource

Tags: android, eclipse

In my app, I decided to change a resource (a PNG file). So, I delete the old one and add the new one with the same name. However, when I run my app in both my phone and the emulator, I still see the old picture !!

I tried all these options:

- Cleaning the project.
- Refreshing the project folder.
- Closing the project then opening it again.
- Exiting Eclipse and launch it again.
- Uninstalling the old version of the app from the phone before run it again.

For those who may ask about how I use this resource (PNG file), I assign a XML selector file as an ImageButton's drawable. My resource is referenced in that XML file.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem a few weeks ago. It was becouse i had en error in a XML file and so the "R" Class wasn't build new. Maybe its the same?

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to create a new AVD and run it there. If the old version still shows, then you know it's hidden in the APK. If it doesn't, then you know the original AVD is still caching it somewhere.

Comment: @PKeidel If there is an error in a XML file, Eclipse won't run the app. In my case, it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The trick was to choose a different name for my image, modify my xml selector file and re-build the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should change the Modified Date of the file to later. I did it.
Use this http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filedatech.html

Answer (score 1):

Look through your project's folders for other png files.  Many mobile platforms use `pngcrush` to optimize pngs for mobile, and it is caching them somewhere.  When you replaced the file, the IDE didn't notice and hasn't recrushed the new file.  The old files will be somewhere in either the workspace's folder, or less likely, Eclipse's application support folders.

Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Changing an image resource file won't cause Eclipse to build a new version. Try modifying a source file by adding a new line, deleting the line, then saving the file. Eclipse should then rebuild your app when you launch it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. I did modify my code but nothing happened !

Comment: Never mind. I solved it. The trick was to choose a different name for my image, modify my xml selector file and re-build the project. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is the closest one to my solution. edit it so that I can accept it

Comment: That's still a hack-ish solution.  I'm sure the files are SOMEWHERE - it can't be using your old images from nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clean the project before rebuilding it, this removes all previous states and should update resource files if you've changed them in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a bad habit of compiling all your code to a structure within it's .metadata directory. Not sure if this is the case for your mobile app though.

Try searching the .metadata directory for the original png and modifying/deleting it there. We've had the same issue with deploying to web servers previously and Eclipse not picking up the changes.